# Cannot open oracle 9i database: ORA-16038: log 4 sequence# 1781 cannot be archived

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

my server was unexpectedly rebooted.

after the server boot up I received the following error when trying to start up the database:

```
ORA-16038: log 4 sequence# 1781 cannot be archived
ORA-19504: failed to create file ""
ORA-00312: online log 4 thread 1: "[LOCATION OF LOG]"
```

is there anything I can do about this?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check how much free space you have on archive destination FS ,Clean up some space and try again 
should work

you can also clean up logs ***if you dont need any them*** from RMAN 
`RMAN> delete archivelog all;` OR ***clean up not required logs*** `delete archivelog until time 'xxxx'`

Comment: I think a bit more investigation is warranted before you start blowing away archive logs.

Comment: Thanks allot, I hade 4KB of free space on the archive drive, cleaned it up and it works